# Can you encounter an Unown not in the 28 Unown species?

Tags: pokemon-series, pokemon-gold-silver-crystal

I encountered an Unown and I don't remember it in the 28 unknown species so fast in Pokémon Gold.

[image: Unown encounter]

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! Can you be more clear on what you are asking? I could instantly tell that is the Unown for the letter B

Comment: What's "so fast" here? It's hard to tell what you're asking

Answer (score 5):

Yes that Unown exists and is correct.

Here you have a image with all 28 forms that the Unowns can have:

[image]

As you can see that Unown is the second one, Unown B.

Comment: Thank you. If you think my answer answers your question, please mark it as valid, with the tick on the left. Thank you!

Comment: It is also should be noted that in Gen 2 each of the 4 puzzle releases different Unown to be caught